# Order WooCommerce Products by Rating

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

In the latest version of Woocommerce API, (the WP REST API v2), the filters have been removed. Earlier I was using the following URL to get products ordered by their `average_rating`.

`products?search=helloWorld&order=desc&filter[orderby]=meta_value_num&filter[orderby_meta_key]=_wc_average_rating`

Now since filters have been removed, I am struggling to get the same output without using filters. I could not find anyway to order products according to their rating. I am also aware of the [REST Filter Plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter) but before going forward that direction, I want to make sure if there is an alternative way.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change from orderby_meta_key to meta_key 
Final code will be as:
products?search=helloWorld&order=desc&filter[orderby]=meta_value_num&filter[meta_key]=_wc_average_rating